# Chi-squared test: Investigating fruit flies attraction to different colours

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have a few questions about the Chi-squared test. First of all, this is what I was investigating:

H0: Fruit flies show no difference in attraction to light of different colours

**Protocol:**
20 fruit flies put in tube. Tube is marked into 3 equal sections along its length.

Tube shaken so flies collect at bottom. LED of chosen color shone at the top of the tube for 1.5 mins, and number of flies in each section counted.

6 different colors used.

**Results:**
I was told to use the chi-squared test for each color. This is how I used the test for Red (value came out as 4.03):

[image]

The expected frequency is 6.67 because there were 20 flies in each tube and three equal sections, so 20/3.

**Questions**
How many degrees of freedom were there? 6 Different colors used so should it be 6-1= 5 degrees?
Or since there were only 3 sections in each tube, would it be 3-1 = 2 degrees?

A second question: I used the Chi squared test for each of the 6 colours. If the chi squared values for a few colors were below the table values and not statistically significant e.g. Red and Green, but the other colors were, can I reject the null hypothesis?

---

**Update**

```
Repeat 1:
        Layer
Color     bottom  middle  top
  white        1       2   17
  blue         5       1   14
  red          5       3   12
  orange       5       3   12
  yellow       4       2   14
  green        8       0   12
```

[image]

Does this look ok?

**Update 2**

Is it possible to avoid three way contingency tables by just adding up the results from my three repeats? Also the critical value, taking p = 0.05 and df=10 is **18.3**  - quite a lot smaller than the value I got below, so am I doing the maths wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Just a query on your experiment design - could there be some bias due to the flies settling near to the end where they were shaken ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a 'one-way' or 'goodness-of-fit' chi-squared test here six times over.  You should be using a chi-squared test of independence on a two-way contingency table.  In addition, as @DJohnson notes below, you need to use the actual counts observed, not average counts (I'm not sure I understand how you say you got $6.67$ flies in the bottom layer, for example.)  That is, you need to set up a contingency table like this:

```
         Layer
Color     bottom  middle  top  sum
  red          7       3   10   20
  green        #       #    #   20
  blue         #       #    #   20
  orange       #       #    #   20
  purple       #       #    #   20
  yellow       #       #    #   20
```

Then run your chi-squared test.  The degrees of freedom for  chi-squared test is $(r-1)(c-1)$ (i.e., the number of rows minus 1 times the number of columns minus 1).  In your case that would be: $5\times 2 = 10$.

---

*Update:*  If you have three repeated versions of this experiment, you have (in some sense) three two-way contingency tables, or (more correctly) a three-way contingency table.  You want to test if there is a difference amongst the rows with the iterations taken into account.  The general way to analyze mult-way contingency tables is to use the [log linear model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-linear_analysis) (which is actually a dressed-up Poisson GLiM).  I describe this in more detail here: [$\chi^2$ of multidimensional data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/147925/7290).  Below, I create two fake datasets using `R`, one I call "`.n`" (for 'null', because there isn't a relationship between the color and the layer), and the other I call "`.a`" (for 'alternative', because the relationship you are interested in does exist).

```r
dft = expand.grid(layer=c("bottom","middle","top"), 
                  color=c("blue", "green", "orange", "red", "white", "yellow"),
                  Repeat=1:3)
dft   = dft[,3:1]
dft.n = data.frame(dft, count=c(rep(c( 3,6,11), times=6), 
                                rep(c( 6,7, 7), times=6), 
                                rep(c(11,6, 3), times=6)))
dft.a = data.frame(dft, 
             count=c(c(3,6,11), c(11,6, 3), c(11,6, 3), c(3,6,11), c(3,6,11), c(11,6, 3),
                     c(3,6,11), c(11,6, 3), c(11,6, 3), c(3,6,11), c(3,6,11), c(11,6, 3),
                     c(3,6,11), c(11,6, 3), c(11,6, 3), c(3,6,11), c(3,6,11), c(11,6, 3) ))
tab.n = xtabs(count~color+layer+Repeat, dft.n)
# , , Repeat = 1
#         layer
# color    bottom middle top
#   blue        3      6  11
#   green       3      6  11
#   orange      3      6  11
#   red         3      6  11
#   white       3      6  11
#   yellow      3      6  11
# 
# , , Repeat = 2
#         layer
# color    bottom middle top
#   blue        6      7   7
#   green       6      7   7
#   orange      6      7   7
#   red         6      7   7
#   white       6      7   7
#   yellow      6      7   7
# 
# , , Repeat = 3
#         layer
# color    bottom middle top
#   blue       11      6   3
#   green      11      6   3
#   orange     11      6   3
#   red        11      6   3
#   white      11      6   3
#   yellow     11      6   3
tab.a = xtabs(count~color+layer+Repeat, dft.a)
# , , Repeat = 1
#         layer
# color    bottom middle top
#   blue        3      6  11
#   green      11      6   3
#   orange     11      6   3
#   red         3      6  11
#   white       3      6  11
#   yellow     11      6   3
# 
# , , Repeat = 2
#         layer
# color    bottom middle top
#   blue        3      6  11
#   green      11      6   3
#   orange     11      6   3
#   red         3      6  11
#   white       3      6  11
#   yellow     11      6   3
# 
# , , Repeat = 3
#         layer
# color    bottom middle top
#   blue        3      6  11
#   green      11      6   3
#   orange     11      6   3
#   red         3      6  11
#   white       3      6  11
#   yellow     11      6   3
```

I run a quickie log-linear analysis on both.  The models are listed from `0`, which is the 'saturated' model, through `2`, which has dropped terms.  Note that in R it is typical to list models in order from smallest to largest, but the result of the `anova()` call refers to the nested model as "`Model 1`", which makes the names not correspond well; try not to be thrown off by this.  For the null dataset, `Model 2` differs from `Model 1` (i.e., `m.1.n` differs from `m.2.n`), meaning that the `layers` are not independent of the `Repeats`.  On the other hand, `Model 3` does not differ from `Model 2` (i.e., `m.0.n` differs from `m.1.n`), meaning that the `layer*Repeat` pattern does not differ by color.  In addition, `Model 3` does not differ from the `Saturated` model (because it *is* the saturated model).

```r
library(MASS)
m.0.n = loglm(~color*layer*Repeat, tab.n)
m.1.n = loglm(~color+layer*Repeat, tab.n)
m.2.n = loglm(~color+layer+Repeat, tab.n)
anova(m.2.n, m.1.n, m.0.n)
# LR tests for hierarchical log-linear models
# 
# Model 1:
#  ~color + layer + Repeat 
# Model 2:
#  ~color + layer * Repeat 
# Model 3:
#  ~color * layer * Repeat 
# 
#           Deviance df Delta(Dev) Delta(df) P(> Delta(Dev)
# Model 1   59.55075 44                                    
# Model 2    0.00000 40   59.55075         4              0
# Model 3    0.00000  0    0.00000        40              1
# Saturated  0.00000  0    0.00000         0              1

m.0.a = loglm(~color*layer*Repeat, tab.a)
m.1.a = loglm(~color+layer*Repeat, tab.a)
m.2.a = loglm(~color+layer+Repeat, tab.a)
anova(m.2.a, m.1.a, m.0.a)
# LR tests for hierarchical log-linear models
# 
# Model 1:
#  ~color + layer + Repeat 
# Model 2:
#  ~color + layer * Repeat 
# Model 3:
#  ~color * layer * Repeat 
# 
#           Deviance df Delta(Dev) Delta(df) P(> Delta(Dev)
# Model 1   87.47794 44                                    
# Model 2   87.47794 40    0.00000         4          1e+00
# Model 3    0.00000  0   87.47794        40          2e-05
# Saturated  0.00000  0    0.00000         0          1e+00
```

For the alternative dataset, `Model 2` does not differ from `Model 1` (i.e., `m.1.a` differs from `m.2.a`), meaning that the `layers` are independent of the `Repeats`.  On the other hand, `Model 3` does differ from `Model 2` (i.e., `m.0.a` differs from `m.1.a`), meaning that the `layer*Repeat` pattern does differ by color.  (And again, `Model 3` is the `Saturated` model.)

Comment: The OP should note that actual counts are being used, not average count.

Comment: Thanks for your help! We ran the experiment three times which is why there are decimals in the observed data. If average counts cannot be used, is there any way I could run the test so that all the data collected in the three repeats is used?

Comment: If we take as the paradigm of a test of independence Agresti's "marital satisfaction" versus "husband v wife" (how quaint...), it sounds conceptually different, doesn't it? Here we are looking at whether the flies distribute themselves homogeneously across different shades of light. What am I missing?

Comment: @poogooflupduck, can you say more about how your experiment was set up? Did you use the same flies in each iteration? Did you keep track of where the same fly ended up on each trial?

Comment: @gung We used the same flies in each iteration and did not keep track of where a specific fly ended up at the end of 1.5 mins of light. We simply counted how many flies were in each section.

Comment: @AntoniParellada, I'm not sure I follow your question. The study question here is about differences by light color. Imagine the distributions were bottom: 11, middle: 6, top 3, for every color. They are the same by color but differ from homogeneity. What should we say in answer to the study question? I think the question of homogeneity does not answer the study question.

Comment: @gung Would it make sense to set up 3 contingency tables, each using data from one of the replicates, to get 3 chi squared values?

Comment: I re-read the study design, and I think the confusion is the variable ("bottom/middle/top"),  which is not really what we want to investigate (or is it?). What we really want to see is the different attraction to different light wavelengths (?).

Comment: I've used the table above with my data - does the updated table look good? Thx for everyone's help

Comment: @AntoniParellada, the study asks if "fruit flies... [differ]... in attraction to light of different colours". They want to know if the column values differ by row. That is a test of independence of a 2-way contingency table. The added wrinkle here is that there are 3 repeats of the study that need to be accounted for as well.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer @gung .Surely it's possible to avoid three way contigency tables by aggregating the data from all of my repeats - so the sum of each color would be 60 flies, and I would expect 20 flies in each section

Comment: @gung What about about the number of counts? Shouldn't the chi-squared break down with so few observations in some cells? Also, is there a multidimensional version of the Fisher's exact test?

Comment: @poogooflupduck, you don't want to aggregate, b/c there can be relationships w/ the repeats. There is no problem w/ having a 3-way contingency table.

Comment: @Firebug, the expected <5 rule is now known to be too conservative (see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/159063/7290)), & Fisher's exact test isn't necessarily ideal either (see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14226/7290)). FWIW, the log-linear model is just a Poisson GLiM, so there is no issue with low counts at all.

Answer (score 4):

Gung's test is a test of independence in the two-way classification table. Additional tests are possible, as described in Wicken's book *Multiway Contingency Tables Analysis for the Social Sciences*, one of the last, great treatments of this topic before the advent of tensor models. As Wickens notes:

> There are three different experimental procedures that generate
>   two-way tables of frequencies. These lead to different models for the
>   population of scores, although the actual tests are the same. The
>   three null hypotheses are referred to as hypotheses of *homogeneity*, of
>   *independence* and of *unrelated classification*...one way to distinguish
>   among the three descriptions is to look at the roles of the marginal
>   frequency distributions (p.22)

In the OP's case, a test of homogeneity seems most appropriate. It is one in which the characteristics of the population are embodied in the row conditional probabilities. Using Gung's table setup, the expected counts for each color by layer cell are conditioned on the "Sum" column:

> The null hypothesis tested here is that the distributions of the
>   responses across the populations are the same...Thus, one speaks of
>   this as a test of the *homogeneity* of the populations. More
>   abstractly, the probabilistic structure underlying these data is a
>   pair of binomial distributions (p. 23)

This test differs from the test of independence in that a single, fixed marginal is being used -- as opposed to the combined row and column marginals in the test of independence.

The test for unrelatedness involves fixed row and column marginals and isn't appropriate for this data (i.e., all marginals would sum to 20).